# How long does it takes to encrypt a 1TB usb disk?

Tags: hard-drive, encryption

I got this 1TB WD usb Disk. I want to encrypt the whole partition using Ubuntu disk utility with `ext4`+`luks` and fill up with zeros the space.

Any idea how can I estimate how long it will take? The tool does not reports this time.

The disk is a WD My Passport Ultra, that comes with hardware encryption but dunno how to use it on Linux. Looks like the software it is only available for Windows and MAC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Caveat: I have not tried this myself*

What does the INITIAL encryption do in practice?

For all data:
 - Read a bunch of the data
 - Process it in a special way
 - Write it back to disk

Add the time to null out all free space (write zeroes).

**Answer:**
So the processing time should be similar to reading out all contents, then writing it back, with a slight penalty for processing it in between.

---

**For estimated read speed of a drive:***
Open a terminal and type/copy + execute this  (press ENTER on it).

```
dev="/dev/sdb"; echo "About to do READ-speed test on $dev"; sudo hdparm -Tt $dev
```

`man hdparm` will tell what it actually does.

Use `lsblk` to find out things to type into `dev="..."`